# TCL Tool Command Language tclsh - Script for Cisco SPA508G Phone Sidecar Auto-attendant

Tags: cisco, voip, voice, cisco-voip

Using Cisco SPA508G phones with SPA500S Sidecar Console.

In the Cisco UI Sidecar programming is the script:

```
fnc=blf+sd+cp;sub=108@$PROXY;nme=Steve J.
```

I need both `sub=108@$PROXY` and `sub=408@$PROXY` on the same line or used with a script operator so that the 108 and 408 Sidecar extensions light up the same RED LEDs when either of those two phone extensions are being used.

Can I put two sub= arguments on the same script line separated by an operator which will light the Red LED light if either one or the other is true?

Thanks - Steve J.

Comment: In the script below, only  ;sub=108@$PROXY;   works.    ;sub=408@$PROXY; does not do anything.                                                                                                      
 fnc=blf+sd+cp;sub=408@$PROXY;sub=108@$PROXY;nme=Stv J. KF

Comment: In TCL Tool Command Language, is there a way to join two commands or actions to perform so that both actions are performed instead of just one  - on Cisco Phone SPA508G?  A statement which is similar to "and" logic statement?     Such as   ;sub=408@$PROXY;  and  ;sub=408@$PROXY;   ?